Weird character conversion when _X2069_ is contained in input sheet for node-xlsx
I'm currently building a small command-line tool with Node and node-xlsx to parse and process some Excel files, and I noticed that whenever the input contains the sequence
_X2069_
node-xlsx seems to convert it to Unicode character U+2069 (Pop Directional Isolate).
Here's a minimal example:


const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');

function getData(excelSheet) {
    data = [];
    excelData = excelSheet[0]["data"]
    length = 0
    // Find the number of rows with actual data and filter out blank rows at the end
    for (let i = 0; i < excelData.length; i++) {
        if (excelData[i][0] != undefined) {
          data.push([]);
          data[i].push(excelData[i][0]); // only first column for now
        }
    }
    return data;
}

const workSheet = xlsx.parse('./input.xlsx');
let rows = getData(workSheet);
console.log(rows);



And here's my input (contents of input.xlsx):
_X2069_
_Y2069_
_Z2069_

The output is:
[ [ '\u2069⁩' ], [ '_Y2069_' ], [ '_Z2069_' ]
which appears like:

My current workaround is to replace all occurrences of U+2069 with the original string, but that seems hacky, and I'm afraid that 2069 isn't the only value that is automagically converted.
How can I prevent this erroneous conversion?

I tried the code in my machine, but it does parse correctly, I think it has something to do with the xlsx file. Maybe you can share that file here?

@damzaky Apparently, it's not so easy to share binary input files on SO. I've asked in Meta how best to approach this. For the time being, I shared it in OneDrive - see https://1drv.ms/x/c/a617387b9c48af6f/EXBz2POg3P1OjdAEKJreJHUBQsZkPtrVN1w5j1vx-Tkk9g?e=gytGSM

Did you try using the type: 'binary' option to parse? I couldn't reproduce, it worked for me, but here's the options you can try: https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs/src/commit/2669c7cf1c8a119f667d2d58c183c35073bb6e2f/packages/s/src/xlsx.d.ts#L104

Also, check this issue: https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs/issues/72

@morganney Setting the type to 'binary' seems to have no effect - I still get the same error.

I'm curious what happens for you if you change from uppercase to lowercase _x?

@morganney lowercase _x works as expected - so far, I've only seen the problem for uppercase _X, but I haven't checked all characters exhaustively.

Have you tried using the xlsx library directly instead of the xlsx-node wrapper and use the Cell Objects API? https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/cell You can use the r field to access the rich text value. Read the file with dense: true and use regex to remove the XML tag, for example: sheet["!data"].map(row => row[0].r.replaceAll(/<[^>]*>/gm, ""))

@FahmiNoorFiqri The problem is also present in the xlsx library. It's now a confirmed bug, see https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs/issues/3177#issuecomment-11165

The root cause is a bug in sheetjs (the library that's being used by node-xlsx). From the issue discussion:

In XLSX, certain unicode characters are encoded using a special
representation _x####_ based on the hexadecimal code. For example, the
string _x2069_ is actually stored as _x005F_x2069_ (where the first
underscore is encoded as _x005F_, the character code for _)
The current code treats the x as case insensitive, so _X2069_ is
treated as the encoded version of the string.

It's fixed in the current development version (_X is no longer treated as "special", only _x).
